# Jenkins Token not working for a specific user

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Figured to try my luck here hoping someone will help me out.

So here is the situation. My jenkins is connected to our AD using the ad plugin.
We have 2 accounts (1 account is mine the other is a service account i want to set up). 
I have given admin permissions to the service accounts so config wise.. both accounts are the same in jenkins.

So logging in Jenkins with the service account I have all the permissions I want/need and I can run a build just fine.

However when I try to use the [python jenkins](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) only my account is able to run the builds with a generated token for that account. The service account is getting error 403- unauthorized.
What could be the difference between the 2 accounts when from a jenkins pov they have identical permissions.. 
Note: the build i am trying to work is literally a dummy job at the moment.. simply to check if I am passing the correct parameters..

Any pointers for what to look/read would be welcome!

Comment: the token to remote trigger the job do you mean?

Comment: Well, for authentication, not the token on the job itself

Comment: Are you referring to Jenkins-crumb as a token or the API Key Token available in $Jenkins_URL/user/$UserID/configure?

Comment: The user api token you generate for your user.. I dont see why 1 user would work and the other not when they have the same access in the security plugin/ and when you browse the console directly when logged in